# Convert Oracle query about unique number to SQL Server 2008

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008

Can anyone help me convert this from Oracle to SQL Server 2008?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq

    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9999
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 5
    CACHE 30;

seq.nextval
```

Comment: See this on DBA.SE http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/3307/630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to convert this to SQL Server as SQL Server is one of the few DBMS that does not support sequences.

If this is used to generate an artificial primary key, you need to look into identity columns or use GUIDs as a PK replacement.

But even if switch to identity columns there is no way to retrieve the "next value" for them. They are only assigned when inserting new rows.

Comment: SQL Server 2011 ("Denali") will have sequences... see [Aaron Bertrand's blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/11/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-sequence) for details

Comment: Can you help me with some code..I am not very familiar with t-sql syntax

Comment: @SiCd: just declare your PK column as "identity" (`pk_column integer not null identity`) and it will automatically be assinged a new value upon insert. When only needing that value for inserting that is actually much easier than Oracle's solution (but less flexible)